# Vscode escaping a slash before using a variable

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, escaping

I was checking out the VS Code snippets the other day, and upon wanting to create a certain snippet I stumbled upon this problem:

```
"body": [
            "test=\"some\\path\\$1\""
        ]
```

I want to escape the slash after 'path' but I dont want to escape the variable, which does now happen since it's the same notation as \$. But I want to escape the slash and just let my $1 be.

Any ideas on how to "unescape" this? I tried doing the string separately, but I couldnt find a way to concatenate strings either!

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
"test=\"some\\path\\\\$1\""
```

this gives:

```
test="some\path\[cursor here]"
```