# How to auto-escape a special char in VS Code Snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to write a snippet for Debugging in TYPO3.

This is my Snippet-Code in php.json file:

```
"TYPO3 Extbase DebuggerUtility": {
    "prefix": "ee",
    "body": [
        "\\TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Utility\\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($1,'$1');",
        "$0"
    ],
    "description": "TYPO3 Extbase DebuggerUtility"
},
```

If I want to debug something liket this : **$this->settings['key']** I get this code:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($this->settings['key'],'$this->settings['key']');
```

But it should looks like this

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($this->settings['key'],'$this->settings[\'key\']');
```

With escaped ' in the second part of that snippet.

**EDIT**

Thank you, but I think you missunderstood the question.

I don't want to escape a static character. I want to use the snippet and when I type the first $1-content it should be $this->settings['someKey'] **but the second $1** (which is near the same) should automatically escape the ' chars I write, that I don't do this manually by hand.

So if i type ' 
first $1: `'` second $1: `\'` that my Debug looks like this

> Debug:
>
> $this->settings['someKey']
>
> contentOfsomeKey

I I don't escape the **' signs** inside the "title of the debug" it breaks the string because ' wraps the debug-title.

In other words: I want to escape the content of the second $1 variable not the variable or the '-wrap in the snippet.

I hope I could clarify my issue.

Comment: There are a number of answers already on this; see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302768/vscode-escaping-a-slash-before-using-a-variable

Comment: thx @Mark / Bernd - I updated my question, your answers doesn't fit my question

Answer (score -1):

If you want escape characters `\` in your output you need to insert escaped escape characters: `\\` this should result in single escape characters.
You might need an additional escape character if the following character needs an additional escaping:  one backslash before quote `\'` = `\\`+ `\'` = `\\\'`

`